# Efficiently apply calculation to Pandas DataFrame based on condition?

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, iteration, list-comprehension

This is my first time using Stack Overflow. I am quite new to coding and Pandas, so please bear with me. I am practicing manipulating data using Python/Pandas instead of Excel, and I've come across the following problem...

I am trying to standardize values for particular columns by year. My data set is rather small so the approach I took (shown below) works well, however, I'm fairly certain it is not a great way to accomplish this task. Is there a better way to do this with list comprehensions or applying a function to the DataFrame? (P.S. any other resources you could recommend for learning about those topics or for examples would be greatly appreciated!)

Sample Data:

```
IN: df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[2018,10,100,50], [2018,11,110,30], [2017,12,120,10], [2017, 15, 115, 40]], columns=['Year','c1','c2','c3'])
OUT:
   Year  c1   c2   c3
0  2018  10  100   50
1  2018  11  110   30
2  2017  12  120   10
3  2017  15  115   40
```

Sample Output:

```
    Year    c1  c2  c3    c1_std      c2_std
0   2018    10  100 50  -0.707107   -0.707107
1   2018    11  110 30  0.707107    0.707107
2   2017    12  120 10  0.707107    0.707107
3   2017    15  115 40  -0.707107   -0.707107
```

*Notice the standardized output is only for 2 of the 3 columns*

My approach:

1. First I created two tables. One for the means by column and year as well as one for standard deviations by column and year.

   ```
   standard_devs = pd.DataFrame(data=[],index=[2018,2017], columns=['c1', 'c2'])
   means = pd.DataFrame(data=[],index=[2018,2017], columns=['c1', 'c2'])  
   for y in [2018,2017]:
       for col in ['c1', 'c2']:
           standard_devs.loc[y,col] = df[df['Year']==y][col].std()
           means.loc[y,col] = df[df['Year']==y][col].mean()
   ```
2. I iterated through my original data frame and calculated the standardized values based on the appropriate year and column.

   ```
   for i in list(df.index):
       for col in ['c1', 'c2']:
           year = df.loc[i,'Year']
           df.loc[i,col+'_std'] = (df.loc[i,col]-means.loc[year, col])/standard_devs.loc[year, col]
   ```

I read before that iterating through a pandas DataFrame is bad practice. I know this method probably cannot scale, so I was wondering how I could be more efficient with my coding.

Thank you all!

Comment: Please add an example for the output, i.e. what result are you after.
Iterating should be last resort in Pandas

Comment: Hi gtomer, I have added in some sample output.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) here to calculate `std` and `mean`. This will calculate the appropriate metric by group and return a Series with the same axis length of `df`:

```
for c in ['c1', 'c2']:
    stds = df.groupby('Year')[c].transform('std')
    means = df.groupby('Year')[c].transform('mean')
    df[f'{c}_std'] = (df[c] - means) / stds
```

---

An alternative approach, would be to temporarily set your index to your groupby key:

```
means = df.groupby('Year')[['c1', 'c2']].mean()
stds = df.groupby('Year')[['c1', 'c2']].std()

(df.join((((df.set_index('Year') - means) / stds))
         .reset_index(drop=True)
         .add_suffix('_std')))
```

[out]

```
   Year  c1   c2  c3    c1_std    c2_std
0  2018  10  100  50 -0.707107 -0.707107
1  2018  11  110  30  0.707107  0.707107
2  2017  12  120  10 -0.707107  0.707107
3  2017  15  115  40  0.707107 -0.707107
```

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for your response! I should have been more clear in my question, but I don't want to standardize every column in the DataFrame. In the example, I only standardized 2 out of the 3 columns. 
Also, if I applied this to a DataFrame that had columns that were non-numeric would this solution work or would it fail because the lengths of the resulting means and stds DataFrames would differ? Thanks!

Comment: It will fail if any of the columns you try to apply this to are non-numeric.